# SQL - How to write a SELECT statement with conditional WHERE/smart logic?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets assume I have a table, where two columns X and Y that are INTs, and other columns exist.

| X | Y | OtherValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 2 | B |
| 2 | 1 | B |
| 3 | 2 | C |

I'm trying to get thee rows based X and Y, where the request may want a specific X or Y, or both. Otherwise, it may want to get all rows (i.e. no X or Y given).

```
SELECT OtherValue
FROM Table
WHERE X = @x
AND Y=@y
```

The closest suggestion I could find suggest something like  `WHERE X=@x OR @x IS NULL`, which makes sense to me, but mentioned that this bad performance antipattern.

Is there another, better way I should be solving this solution?

Comment: That's the standard way.

Comment: BTW, when discussing performance, don't forget to add the dbms tag. (Different products optimize in different ways.)

Comment: Not sure what is creating the text query statement but you could add branching to only add to the WHERE clause if the search value is not null.

Comment: You build the where clause in the application.

Comment: @jarlh If its standard, that's good to know. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't building a bad habit. I've also added the dbms tag mentioned.

Comment: I agree with @SalmanA, it would be most optimal to build the needed query in the app code, or with dynamic SQL on the server side. Alternatively, you could use `WHERE (X = @x OR @x IS NULL) AND (Y = @y OR @y IS NULL) OPTION(RECOMPILE);` as long as it's not executed many times per second. Regardless you should have a composite index on X,Y and another on Y,X.

Comment: Have a look at Erland's [dynamic search conditions](https://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). Though geared towards stored procedures, many of the same concepts apply here.

Comment: Also see [kitchen sink](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) - you don't necessarily have to have a single query that satisfies all combinations of parameters, and you don't necessarily have to recompile every time (doesn't make sense when the only populated param is a PK or unique key, for example).

Comment: "...but mentioned that this bad performance antipattern..." -- if your table has few rows then performance is not an issue. If the table has many rows then you should combine Dynamic SQL with smart indexing to get high performance on the queries. However, if your query naturally returns a massive number of rows, then it's going to be slow no matter what.

Comment: Thanks all. The way SalmanA mentioned does seem a good way to filter for the needed rows outside the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using an `OR` operator can throw off the SQL Server optimizer, and often means you'll end up with a bad plan. For example, when pulling data from the `Table` table, SQL needs to pick one index, and only one, that it'll use to pull all data from that one table. Assuming a `NONCLUSTERED` index exists on X and Y, respectively, those options could look something like this.

- CLUSTERED SCAN: Table scan for all rows where X or Y are matched.
- SEEK on NONCLUSTERED INDEX X (But this won't provide details on Y)
- SEEK on NONCLUSTERED INDEX Y (But this won't provide details on X)

The end result is usually a SCAN of the the CLUSTERED INDEX instead. Going this path, SQL Server knows it can get X and Y in one INDEX SCAN, vs multiple followup steps required when using either of the available SEEKS.

Now, if you have individual INDEXES on each of those columns, you can write a query for each unique combination of input. This ends up being faster because each individual query uses the index that works best for its result set.

The result would look something like this.

```
SELECT OtherValue
FROM Table
WHERE X = @x
    AND @x IS NOT NULL
    AND @y IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT OtherValue
FROM Table
WHERE Y=@y
    AND @y IS NOT NULL
    AND @x IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT OtherValue
FROM Table
WHERE X = @x AND @x IS NOT NULL
    AND Y = @y AND @y IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT OtherValue
FROM Table
WHERE @x IS NULL
    AND @y IS NULL
```

I talk more about the implication of using the `OR` in `UPDATES` on my [blog](https://brendan-mccaffrey.com/2021/12/20/stop-using-the-or-operator/). But the same logic holds true for `SELECT` statements.